# Calculated field in custom table not working

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, powerquery

I'm trying to build a visual in PowerBI that is essentially a matrix with 14 different calculations from different tables into one.
I've managed to set up an example as below and it's pulling through the correct total figure, however when I filter for month (There is another Calendar table) the count does not change. There is a relationship that works between the Sales table and Calendar on the Use_SaleDate to Calendar[Date] (neither have time in the date field). Any idea why it's not working. It should go from 12,943 to 3,561 if the sale was in 2023 for example.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

DAX Visuals work in Filter Context, when you create a table with measures the values are hard coded until you re-open the report, edit the dax code, or force refresh in some way, the values won't change. In simpler words the Filter Context from report view doesn't flow to tables in the model view.

The Calendar table can filter Sales but the filter context here can't filter the measure reference in the table as it is outside the scope of the report. Calculated Table/Columns are not affected by the Filter Context of the report.

What you could do is add the date column in the AW_Matrix_Table and then add those 14 measures, assuming they depend on Date column for the report purpose.